# How to do custom view shapes using swift UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview

How to Display Star Shaped UIView either 5 point star or many?

By Using CGRect am getting square or rectangle shape view , by adding corner radius to it am getting circle shaped view.

How to get star shape UIView

Comment: You can draw the shapes in [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/) and get the swift code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code

```
    let starPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 50, height: 50))
    starPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 45.25, y: 0))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 61.13, y: 23))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 88.29, y: 30.75))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 70.95, y: 52.71))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 71.85, y: 80.5))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 45.25, y: 71.07))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 18.65, y: 80.05))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 19.55, y: 52.71))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2.21, y: 30.75))
    starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 29.37, y: 23))
    starPath.close()
    starPath.lineWidth = 1
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    starPath.stroke()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = starPath.cgPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this thread: [How to make star shape with bezier path in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343458/how-to-make-star-shape-with-bezier-path-in-ios)

There you can find a UIBezierpath, that draws a star.
You can then use this star path and use it as the path for a CAShapeLayer.

Then you have to add this CAShapeLayer to the layer of your UIView.